# getStats() kurento Java Client Example

Tags: java, webrtc, kurento

I have been trying to find out a good example describing the use of getStats in Kuretno Java client but had no success.
Is there a reference available showing the use of getStats() in the Java client of Kurento?

Answer (score 0):

You might get something from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kurento/WLW7rQ4C68w) apparently you have to go [here](https://github.com/lulop-k/kms-monitoring-java/blob/master/src/main/java/org/kurento/tutorial/kmsmonitor/KmsMonitor.java#L112)

Comment: Is this the only example available?